# takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess, popen

I would like to run a command line tool to run in a separate function and passed to the button click the additional command for this program but each time I get this as a response.

**takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess


class StdoutRedirector(object):
    def __init__(self,text_widget):
        self.text_space = text_widget

    def write(self,string):
        self.text_space.insert('end', string)
        self.text_space.see('end')

class CoreGUI(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.InitUI()

        button = Button(self.parent, text="Check Device", command= self.adb("devices"))
        button.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=1)

    def InitUI(self):
        self.text_box = Text(self.parent, wrap='word', height = 6, width=50)
        self.text_box.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan = 2, sticky='NSWE', padx=5, pady=5)
        sys.stdout = StdoutRedirector(self.text_box)

    def adb(self, **args):
        process = subprocess.Popen(['adb.exe', args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        print(process.communicate())
        #return x.communicate(stdout)


root = Tk()
gui = CoreGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Maik/PycharmProjects/Lernen/subprocessExtra.py", line 33, in <module>
    gui = CoreGUI(root)
  File "C:/Users/Maik/PycharmProjects/Lernen/subprocessExtra.py", line 18, in __init__
    button = Button(self.parent, text="Check Device", command= self.adb("devices"))
TypeError: adb() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception ignored in: <__main__.StdoutRedirector object at 0x013531B0>
AttributeError: 'StdoutRedirector' object has no attribute 'flush'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

can some body help me

there is something wrong with **args

Comment: Can we see the exact error, and the specific line where it happens

Comment: ´Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*/subprocessExtra.py", line 33, in <module>
    gui = CoreGUI(root)
  File "*/subprocessExtra.py", line 18, in __init__
    button = Button(self.parent, text="Check Device", command= self.adb("devices"))
TypeError: adb() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception ignored in: <__main__.StdoutRedirector object at 0x013531B0>
AttributeError: 'StdoutRedirector' object has no attribute 'flush'

Process finished with exit code 1
´

Comment: That should be in the question :^)

Comment: It looks like the code using the redirector is expecting a `flush` method, which you don't provide. Have you tried adding a `flush` method to the redirector? You are also using the `command` attribute wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: I try to understand through code snippets and try as they learn how to code. lambda dont worke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are providing it a positional argument here:

```
button = Button(self.parent, text="Check Device", command= self.adb("devices"))
```

command want's a callback function. and you are passing it the response from the `adb` method. (see here fore more: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

when that line is being called, `self.adb("devices")` is being called. 
if you look at your definition of `adb`

```
def adb(self, **args):
```

You are only asking for 1 positional argument `self` and any number of keyword arguments `**args` then you are calling it `self.adb("devices")` with 2 positional arguments of `self` and `"devices"`

What you will need to do is have an intermediate method, if you want to have the `adb` method more general, or just put `"devices"` into the `adb` method.

**edit**

See also here: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm See the section "Passing Argument to Callbacks"

**edit 2: code example**

If you do this, it should work:

```
button = Button(self.parent, text="Check Device", command=lambda:  self.adb("devices"))
```

and then change your function to a single `*` inlieu of a `**` (keyword arg expansion) See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/6030424 for more explanation.

```
def adb(self, *args):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['adb.exe', args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    print(process.communicate())
    #return x.communicate(stdout)
```

Comment: I would like to use devices not fixed because I want to use the same definition to create other and more agumente yet

Comment: if i add `button = Button(self.parent, text="Check Device", command=lambda: self.adb(self, "devises"))` error say `button = Button(self.parent, text="Check Device", command=lambda: self.adb(self, "devises"))
TypeError: adb() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
Exception ignored in: <__main__.StdoutRedirector object at 0x01193230>
AttributeError: 'StdoutRedirector' object has no attribute 'flush'`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the way you declare `args`: it should be `*args` (one asterisk) instead of `**args` (two asterisks). One asterisk specifies any number of positional arguments, where as two asterisks means any number of named arguments.

Also, you need to pass `args` correct to `adb.exe`:

```
def adb(self, *args):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['adb.exe'] + args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```